# Duplicate Strings with Ambiguity

Tags: data-structures, bioinformatics

I have a large (5-10 million) set of strings with the restricted alphabet of nucleotide symbols (A,T,C, and G) along with a wildcard symbol N.  Each string has an integer associated with it.

I want to find all the unique strings and, for each, sum their integer values.  The 'representative' string for a set of equal strings should be the one with the highest integer value.  For example, given:

```
NTG 9
NAG 6
ANG 5
TTT 2
ATG 2
```

I want the output to be:

```
NTG 14
NAG 6
ATG 2
TTT 2
```

With a dataset of this size pairwise comparisons are not feasible.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure to understand the rule of merging here, why not merge ATG and NTG, for example? you choose ANG because its interger value is greater?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your target output wasn't accurate. It seems more appropriate to match "ATG" to "ANG" (which I have done) instead of matching "ANG" to "NTG" (your stated goal). This solution addresses your given sample set, but may not be helpful for your desired application given the significant difference in scale.

Code:

```
import re

test = """
NTG 9
NAG 6
ANG 5
TTT 2
ATG 2
"""

test = [x.split(" ") for x in test.upper().split("\n") if x != ""]
#print(test)

index = 0
while index < len(test):
    seq = test[index]
    seq_regex = seq[0].replace("N", ".")
    no_match_li = [x for x in test if len(re.findall(seq_regex, x[0])) == 0]
    match_li = [int(x[1]) for x in test if len(re.findall(seq_regex, x[0])) != 0]
    #print(no_match_li, match_li)
    test = [[seq[0], sum(match_li)]] + no_match_li
    index += 1

test = sorted(test, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for seq in test:
    print(seq[0], seq[1])
```

Output:

```
NTG 11
NAG 6
ANG 5
TTT 2
```